# how do I deactivate all cameras in a list except for the one that is currently in use?

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine

I have a list of cameras that the player can switch through using the up and down keys to look around with.

Instead of all cameras being on at the same time when the game starts, I would like it if they were all off until the player switches over to them, then it becomes active. then if I switch again the next camera becomes active and the previous becomes inactive and so on and so forth.

How do I do this?

```
public class CameraManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    public List<Camera> cameras = new List<Camera>();
    
    public int currentCamera;

    public void Awake ()
    {
        cameras.Add(Camera.main);
        cameras.AddRange(FindObjectsOfType<Camera>());
    }

    void incCamera()
    {
        cameras [currentCamera].enabled = false;

        currentCamera++;

        if(currentCamera >= cameras.Count){
            currentCamera = 0;
        }

        cameras [currentCamera].enabled = true;
    }

    void decCamera()
    {
        cameras [currentCamera].enabled = false;
        currentCamera--;

        if(currentCamera < 0){

            currentCamera = cameras.Count-1;
        }
        cameras [currentCamera].enabled = true;
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.UpArrow))
        {
            incCamera();
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.DownArrow))
        {
            decCamera();
        }
```

Comment: Put a for loop in the CameraManager constructor and set one with enable ON and the other to OFF

Comment: how the player is going to choose the camera? is it by incrementing/decreasing the index? or can he choose any camera in the list?

Comment: Side note: You don't need both `[SerializeField]` and `public`. Generally, use `[SerializeField]` if you want the field to be inaccessible to outside classes but still appear in the Editor.

Comment: Another note - adding both `Camera.main` and finding all cameras will ensure that you have two references to the main camera in your List.

Comment: Other than that this seems like it should work. What went wrong exactly?

Comment: I can switch through all the cameras fine but all cameras in the list are active at the same time. Only the "current camera" should be active all other cameras should be inactive until switched to.

The point is to have only one camera active at a time in the game scene and that camera is the camera that is being used by the player.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can move on your list and if current camera is not Camera.main, you can deactivate it:

```
// based on comments, it's better to change your Awake method
private void Awake()
{
    _cameras.AddRange(FindObjectsOfType<Camera>());
}

private void Start()
{
    foreach (var camera1 in _cameras)
    {
        if (camera1 == Camera.main) continue;
        camera1.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }

    // using LINQ
    // foreach (var camera1 in _cameras.Where(camera1 => camera1 != Camera.main))
    // {
    //     camera1.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    // }    
}
```